# Getting xib dismissed

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I have screens: 1st one is xib and 2nd is the controller when I dismiss screen 2. Both screens get dismissed instead of the 2nd controller.

[image] in iOS(Xcode)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please click on help and take the tour. Pictures of code is not very helpful. Please click on edit and paste your code into the question, remove the links, and be sure the code is formatted well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want remove xib then you just need to `removeFromSuperview` so only xib will remove.and also please share your code so we can get idea what you did.

> [subview removeFromSuperview]

.. and if you want to remove viewcontroller as a subview you need to do

```
yourViewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
yourViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
yourViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
```

1) [refer this link for more info](https://guides.codepath.com/ios/Adding-and-Removing-Child-View-Controllers)  2)[Link2](https://medium.com/@johnsundell/using-child-view-controllers-as-plugins-in-swift-458e6b277b54)

Comment: Which one I have to remove 1 or 2.

Comment: @sagarSaw if you just want to remove XIB from viewcontroller then use my code.i will work on any `IBAction`

Comment: func addBottomSheetView(scrollable: Bool? = true) {
        
        self.addChildViewController(bottomSheetVC)
        self.view.addSubview(bottomSheetVC.view)
        bottomSheetVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        
        let height = view.frame.height
        let width  = view.frame.width
        bottomSheetVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
        
        //bottomSheetVC.HeaderLbl1.text="hello all  2"
    }

Comment: I just want to dismiss the tableview screen.

Comment: But when I dismiss the tableview screen its both getting dismissed the xib too.

Comment: @sagarSaw accept answer so it will use other user when they got same problem.Happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should Animation with two views.

```
        presentedView.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(presentedView.transform, 0, DEVICE_HEIGHT);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6f delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:1 initialSpringVelocity:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            presentedView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            appDelegate.window.rootViewController = appDelegate.welcomeViewctrl;
        }];
```